# How to pass a function variable to a jQuery event on a Backbone model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have some problems with Backbone.Validation library, as you know `model.bind("validated", function(...) )`. I have that one in method of Reactjs Component. You can see the code as below, I would like to set the `eMsg` global var but when it is outside of `user.bind` or `user.on`, `eMsg` var is not assigned.

How can I get error from `user.bind` or `user.on` to outside of the statement?

```
handleSubmit : function() {
    var self = this;
    var user = new global.Models.RegisterModel(this.state.model, {validate:true});
    var flag = false;
    var eMsg = null;
    ********* (First Testing) ************
    /*user.bind("validated", function(isValid, model, error) {
    if(!isValid){
        for (var k in error) {
        eMsg += ", " + error[k];
        }
    }else{
        flag = true;
    }
    });*/
    ********* (Sencod Testing) ************
    if( user.isValid() ){
    console.log("success")
    this.setState({msg : "success"})
    }else{
    console.log("error")
    user.on("invalid", function(model, error) {
        console.log("invalid")
        console.log(error);
    })
    this.setState({msg : eMsg})
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reference `eMsg` because the context of your `on` callback is no longer in the scope of your `handleSubmit` function. To bring the scope back you have two options.

### Use jQuery.proxy()

You can bind the context of the object `handleSubmit` belongs to by using `jQuery.proxy()`, like this:

```
user.on("validated", $.proxy(function(isValid, model, error) {
   if(!isValid){
      for (var k in error) {
         this.eMsg += ", " + error[k];
      }
   } else{
      flag = true;
   }
}, this));
```

Now, notice that I pre-pended `this.` to your `eMsg` variable, because there is no way to access local variables of a function outside the function. So here, you have to set up `eMsg` as a property of your object, i.e.

```
handleSubmit : function() {
  this.eMsg = "";
  ...
}
```

All `$.proxy()` does is bind the `$.on` callback function to the context that we give it. Here, obviously it was `this` the context of the object that includes the 'handleSubmit` property.

### Oldschool way (no jQuery)

We could also just pass in a reference to the object itself, which you already stored in the `self` variable. Our delegate would look like,

```
user.on("validated", function(isValid, model, error) {
   if(!isValid){
      for (var k in error) {
         self.eMsg += ", " + error[k];
      }
   } else{
      flag = true;
   }
});
```

where we removed the `$.proxy()` function and used the object context stored in `self`, which is in scope in the closure where you defined your delegate. Again, note that `eMsg` has to be instantiated as a property (`this.eMsg`) in your object.

### Using `this.eMsg`

Now all you have to do to retrieve the error message is refer to `this.eMsg` and your code would look like:

```
if( user.isValid() ){
   console.log("success")
   this.setState({msg : "success"})
} else {
  console.log("error")
  user.on("invalid", function(model, error) {
      console.log("invalid")
      console.log(error);
  })
  this.setState({msg : this.eMsg})
}
```

Comment: Thanks Seebiscuit, that is my needing, i made it. i come up with new case that is 
if( user.isValid() ){
                this.setState({msg : "success"})
            }else{
                var eMsg = "";
                for (var k in user.validationError) {
                    eMsg += user.validationError[k] + ", ";
                }
                this.setState({msg : eMsg})
            }